# Which pets allow training multiple levels without user interaction?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The in-game store's pet section says "Dwellers train to max level without stopping." and shows the image (I think) of a maine coon cat.  Can anyone verify that that is what the Maine Coon cat does?  The information I've seen online just says "improves training time" (as does the Black Lab.)

[image: Fallout Shelter Store Text]

Comment: I've tested with a (19% training time) Maine Coon cat and it definitely does not do this (neither does the Black Lab.)  Is the text in the store incorrect?  Is it for a different pet?  Perhaps it has to be the Legendary version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legendary version has that effect. It is noted "continuous". The pet is called Bangor. I have it and I can confirm it works without stopping until max level.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The pet shown in the graphic you've attached is a "[Maine Coon](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_pets)". The Maine Coons ability is [decreased training time](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/complete-fallout-shelter-pet-list-new-animals-found-game-increase-happiness-speed-497656). Not training to max level without stopping.

As far as I can tell, no pets have that effect. Perhaps it was nerfed in a previous version.